# Django Chat App - Capturing value from URL

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I tried to create a simple Django Chat App. There is no login system.

Whenever a user(e.g. John) tries to create a message, it stores under 'messageroom'

[image]

I tried to pass the username 'John' value in the URL but somehow it is not creating a message as expected.

[image]

Here is my code
Urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('checkview',views.checkview,name='checkview'),
    path('messageroom/<str:room_name>/<str:username>',views.messageroom,name='messageroom'),
]
```

Models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    roomname = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Message(models.Model):
    messagetext = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    messageroom = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{})

def checkview(request):
    room_name=request.POST.get('room_name')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    Roomexists = Room.objects.filter(roomname=room_name)

    if Roomexists.exists():
        return redirect('messageroom/'+room_name+'/'+username) 

    else: 
        newroom = Room(roomname=room_name)
        newroom.save()
        return redirect('messageroom/'+room_name+'/'+username)

def messageroom(request,room_name,username):
    if request.method == "POST":
        messagetext = request.POST.get('message')
        newmessage = Message(messagetext=messagetext,messageroom=room_name,username=username)
        newmessage.save()
    
    listmessages = Message.objects.filter(messageroom=room_name)
    return render(request, 'room.html', {'listmessages':listmessages,'room_name':room_name,'username':username})
```

Room.html

```
    <form id="post-form2" method="POST" action="messageroom">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message" width="100px" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

I want to create messages under the user which should be there on the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### you should pass values in urls in html form like this....

```
<form id="post-form2" method="POST" action="{% url 'messageroom' room_name username %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" width="100px" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>


-------------------------- OR ------------------

<form id="post-form2" method="POST" action="/messageroom/room_name/username/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" width="100px" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```